# How to find first non-repeating element?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

How to find first non-repeating element in an array.
Provided that you can only use 1 bit for every element of the array and time complexity should be O(n) where n is length of array.
Please make sure that I somehow imposed constraint on memory requirements. It is also possible that it can not be done with just an extra bit per element of the string. Also please let me know if it is possible or not?

Comment: that is given an array, find an element that occurs exactly once in the array, and if there are multiple of them, report the first one. Is my description correct?

Comment: So the elements of the array can have 2 values: on bit or off bit?

Comment: what is "non-repeating"? does this mean that the item is unique in the array, or that the strictly next element is different?

Comment: What is the data type of the array? bytes? chars? strings?

Comment: Are there any memory constraints involved ?

Comment: @Shamim: exactly
yes non-repeating means the element that is occuring just once means it is unique. 
Array is not sorted

Comment: What do you mean by "you an only use 1 bit for every element of the array"?

Comment: 1 bit is kind of memory constraint. You can up according to the presence of the element.

Comment: @arvind, does that mean that you can have another container (say a map) which maps the element to a bit to indicate presence?

Comment: @nim: if you can make such a converter use only one bit per entry, yes.

Comment: You could do it in O(N) if you could use a map of all the values and count their presence. I guess this is either a trick question, the detail we have here is incomplete, or the solver is expected to find some clever way of mapping/hashing each entry to an address in an n-bit word..

Comment: @filip-fku: Now you only need to find a map that inserts and finds elements in O(const) to make your statement true.

Comment: I came through some conclusions like, I can make an array of integer of 256 elements storing all the occurrences but it will take 32 bits per character.
Also every character can have 3 types of state :
1. Either it is present in the string just once.
2. Or it is not present at all.
3. Or it is present more than once.
so I can not make an array of boolean variables too.

Comment: Is this a homework? Is this an interview question? Are you sure the phrasing is exact? There's probably no solution to the problem as stated.

Comment: Consequently I can use a total of 2 ints (2*32 bits), so that a bit of first int is set up after its first occurrence and the same index bit is set up in the second integer. Now if at particular index, bit in both the integers are either zero or one then the element is either absent or occurred more than once. But if only one bit at that index is up then element is just unique.

Comment: @n.m. - it is not a homework. I was going through a question where first non-repeating element was to find and the solution was using counter for each character. And this question is the modified version of that question with some constraints.

Comment: @phresnel well a hash map might. Though seemingly a map is not allowed.

Comment: @arvind.mohan, so this is a question you made up? Well, I can't see a solution to this that is both O(n) and allows you to use two states to track three. You can cheat, a map (key exists or not is also a state in addition to a bit in the map, 0 - single, 1 - more than 1 repetition), and the first phase is O(n) - i.e. array scan. But you need to do a second scan to find the first item in the array with value in map of 0. So worst case for such an algorithm is O(2n).

Comment: @Nim, O(2n) is the same as O(n).

Comment: @Caleb, ah okay - fair enough, ignore the last bit of my comment then, it's still difficult to track three states with 1 bit though...

Comment: OK so it is not phrased correctly. You use one bit per each possible value of the element, not onrle bit per element. If you have an array of 10 ASCII characters, you use 256 bits, not 10 bits. This is a big difference.

Comment: The memory requirements are unclear. Giving -1 until you improve the question.

Comment: A bitmap would not work without a limit on the range of the elements.

Comment: @Tomas Telensky: I myself is not confirm about the question, I just imposed some constraints out of nowhere to make this question interesting and from this constraint I mean that since we need to store 3 states of an element, how this work will be done. Can it be done or not?

Comment: @arvind: the memory requirements were not clear to me. Whether we can create data structure of N bits (arbitrary), or if we have extra bit in each of element of the input array to make notes. But its basically the same. OK, retracted the downvote, but still recommend to formulate the question more clear for others.

Comment: you also did not specify the type of the element

Comment: Take a string of alphabets. That will give precise result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say there is no comparison based algorithm, that can do it in O(n). As you have to compare the the first element of the array with all others, the 2nd with all except the first, the 3rd with all except the first = Sum i = O(n^2).

(But that does not necessarily mean that there is no faster algorithm, see sorting: There is a proof that you cant sort fast than O(n log n) if you are comparison based - and there is indeed one faster: Bucket Sort, which can do it in O(n)).

**EDIT**: In one of the other comments I said something about hash functions. I checked some facts about it, and here are the hashmap approach thoughts:

- Obvious approach is (in Pseudocode):

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < maxsize; i++)
      count[i] = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < maxsize; i++) {
     h = hash(A[i]);
     count[h]++;
  }
  first = -1;
  for (i = 0; i < maxsize; i++)
     if (count[i] == 0) {
        first = i;
        break;
     }
  }
  for (i = 0; hash(A[i]) != first; i++) ;
  printf("first unique: " + A[i]);
  ```
- There are some caveats:

  1. How to get `hash`. I did some research on perfect hash functions. And indeed you can generate one in O(n). (*Optimal algorithms for minimal perfect hashing* by George Havas et al. - Not sure how good this paper is, as it claims as Time Limit O(n) but speaks from non linear space limit (which is plan an error, I hope I am not the only seeing the flaw in the this, but according to all theorical computer science I know off time is an upper border for space (as you dont have time to write in more space)). But I believe them when they say it is possible in O(n).
  2. The additional space - here I dont see a solution. Above papers cites some research that says that you need 2.7 bits for the perfect hash function. With the additional `count` array (which you can shorten to the states: Empty + 1 Element + More than 1 Element) you need 2 additional bits per element (1.58 if you assume you can it somehow combine with the above 2.7), which sums up to additional 5 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Here I'm just taking one assumption that the string is Character String, just containing small alphabets, so that I can use one Integer (32 bit) so that with 26 alphabets it will be sufficient to take one bit per alphabet. Earlier I thought to take an array of 256 elements but then it will have 256*32 bits in total. 32 bits per element. But finally I found that I will be unable to do it without one more variable. So the solution is like this with just one integer (32 bits) for 26 alphabets:

```
 int print_non_repeating(char* str)
 {
  int bitmap = 0, bitmap_check = 0;
  int length = strlen(str);
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
   if(bitmap & 1<<(str[i] - 'a'))
     {
        bitmap_check = bitmap_check | ( 1 << (str[i] - 'a');
      }
   else 
      bitmap = bitmap | (1 << str[i] - 'a');
  }
  bitmap = bitmap ^ bitmap_check;
  i = 0;
  if(bitmap != 0)
  {
  while(!bitmap & (1<< (str[i])))
   i++;
  cout<<*(str+i);
   return 1;
  }
  else 
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: this clearly does not meet your original requirement that you only use a single bit! You are using two bits for each *letter*. A bit in `bitmap` and a bit in `bitmap_check`!!

Answer (score 0):

This code finds the first repeating element. havent figured out yet if in the same for loop if it is possible to find the non-repeating element without introducing another for (to keep the code O(n)). Other answers suggest bubble sort which is O(n^2)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max_size 10

int main()
{
    int numbers[max_size] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4 ,2, 7};
    int table[max_size] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int answer = 0, j=0;

  for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++)
  {
    j = numbers[i] %max_size;
    table[j]++;
    if(table[j] >1)
    {
          answer = 1;
          break;
    }
 }
   std::cout << "answer = " << answer ;
}
```

Comment: I guess the if must be in a 2nd loop after the first. I also thought of this, but it has 2 problems: 1. You you dont treat hash collision (e.g. max_size = 5, and the numbers 10 and 15). Only solution that came to my mind is a perfect hash function (which you cant make up in O(n)). 2. you need as additional space your table array, but poster asked only for 1 Bit additional space per Element. With your count you need more than 1 Bit.

Comment: Except multiple values that are not the same could hash to the same index. For example for size 10, the numbers 1 and 11 would both "hash" to index 1..

Comment: SORRY guys, had just copy pasted previous answer to modify it for my answer, posted without compiling. I have did the corrections. Yes the table array takes extra space, but i thought i could be optimized. @filip-fku , yes 1,11, fails, but we can certainly have some workaround it in O(n)?

Comment: I was also about to suggest the hash table. You just need a normal hash container. std::hashmap, for example.

Comment: Hmm - what am I missing here - what does an `answer = 0` or `answer = 1` mean?

Comment: @Nim. Oh. answer = 1 means a repeating element has been found. 0 otherwise. It is also possible to find which element was repeated.

Comment: @Shubhendu, I realise that, but question was, what has this got to do with the OP's question. The problem is to find the **first non-repeating** element...

Comment: Ok. What does first mean? Is it 5 for the given array in code? If so, i messed up. I am finding first repeating element.

Comment: @Shubhendu, yip, it's 5, and your code is not finding that! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a modified bucketsort as exemplified below. However, you need to know the max value in the array passed into the firstNonRepeat method. So this runs at O(n).
For comparison based methods, the theoretical fastest (at least in terms of sorting) is O(n log n). Alternatively, you can even use modified versions of radix sort to accomplish this.

```
public class BucketSort{
    //maxVal is the max value in the array
    public int firstNonRepeat(int[] a, int maxVal){
        int [] bucket=new int[maxVal+1];

        for (int i=0; i<bucket.length; i++){
            bucket[i]=0;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            if(bucket[a[i]] == 0) {
                bucket[a[i]]++;             
            } else {
                return bucket[a[i]];
            }
        }
    }
}
```